# can gcc's map file show each sections according to every source files?

Tags: gcc, map-files

By default, gcc's map show different sections, with relative source files' object. In this case, we cannot see each sections for a specific file directly.

A way is do searching for the specific source file.
However, if we want to statistic every source file, it's a huge work to find out the results.
Is there any smart ways, such as using a specific option?